# Removing Advanced MacCleaner Icon from Lauchpad

Tags: macos, launchpad

Had problem with "Advanced Mac Cleaner".  After some effort, and plenty of time, I think I have found and removed all files concerning this malware.  My only apparent remaining problem is that the Advanced MacCleaner icon remains in my Launchpad.  I really, REALLY don't want to bring any of the amc files back from trash unless I absolutely have to (and would prefer to empty trash entirely after I am sure this whole problem is solved.)  Anyone got a fairly easy fix for this final step that a basic laymen (computer wise) like me could implement w/o too much difficulty?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure this has already been answered [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/144756/how-to-remove-an-icon-from-launchpad-that-does-not-appear-in-the-finder). They used a terminal command to remove the application. This is the command that was listed:

```
sqlite3 $(sudo find /private/var/folders -name com.apple.dock.launchpad)/db/db "DELETE FROM apps WHERE title='APP_NAME_CASE_SENSITIVE';" && killall Dock
```