# How to delete App (files with cross sign) that cant delete from Application on Mac

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, catalina

Due to my new Mac running hot overheating issue, I found an extension app called "Turbo Boost Switcher" to see if I can control heat generation.

However, since it can't it run properly, I want to delete it after. Then I realized, I cant remove it from the launchpad nor from the Application folder.

When I try to search what are leftover in the computer, I found that the files were all shown with a prohibitory sign as shown.

[image: in Library-staged extentions]

How can I locate and trash these icons?

Comment: Where did you fine the file with the prohibitory sign?

Answer (score 1):

The prohibitory symbol means the application will not run on your machine.

I'd recommend either user128733 or CousinCocaine approach as seen here:

[How to remove an icon from launchpad that does not appear in the Finder?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/144756/how-to-remove-an-icon-from-launchpad-that-does-not-appear-in-the-finder/181851)

Application cleaner tend to be OK.  FYI: General mac cleaners are to be avoided.

https://nektony.com/how-to/delete-apps-from-launchpad